# Destructure a nested object, but keep a reference to the nested object

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I have a simple use-case, but I think it's not possible with ES6 syntax. I'd like to use object destructuring to retrieve certain known properties from a nested object, but I'd also like a reference to that nested object so that I can pass it along to other functions which may care about other properties.

Here's an example object:

```
var record = {
    name: "foo",
    metadata: {
        createdDate: "2017-02-19",
        lastModifiedDate: "2018-07-24",
        type: "bar"
    }
};
```

At a certain point in my code, I'd like to extract some values from the metadata. At the same time, I'd also like to extract the entire metadata object:

```
let {
    metadata: {
        createdDate
    }
} = record;

if ( date( createdDate ).before( NEW_FEATURE_DATE ) ){
    oldFeature( metadata );
} else {
    newFeature( metadata );
}
```

Unfortunately, my reference to the `metadata` property is used purely for destructuring... it's value is `undefined` (technically, being undefined, it has no value).

I know I can solve this with something like

```
let {
        metadata: {
            createdDate
        }
    } = record,
    metadata = record.metadata;
```

or

```
let {
        metadata
    } = record,
    {
        createdDate
    } = metadata;
```

... but that seems kind of clumsy, doesn't it? Is there something I'm missing, or is this just a "gap" in the syntax?

Comment: With less indentation, the last snippet doesn't look that clumsy actually.

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, it's a simple example. Imagine a couple dozen properties.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just add another same property without destructuring.

```js
var record = { name: "foo", metadata: { createdDate: "2017-02-19",  lastModifiedDate: "2018-07-24", type: "bar" } };

let { metadata: { createdDate }, metadata } = record;
//    ^^^^^^^^                                        for nested destructuring
//                               ^^^^^^^^             for the value

console.log(metadata);
console.log(createdDate);
```

Comment: Awesome! I had hope that I was missing something simple like that.

Comment: How is this called technically?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not you want the nested object to also contain the destructured properties.

If you do then then see [Nina Scholz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51506725/1915893)

If you don't then the use the `...rest` syntax like so:

```
let {
    metadata: {
      createdDate,
      ...metadataExceptForCreatedDate
  }
} = record;
```

Comment: Cool. Nina's answer gave me what I need, but this is still very useful information for future reference.

Comment: Glad to help. Her answer is also very helpful indeed.